# How do I modify the generated routes for a resource in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In essence, I want to to be able to have URLs like these.

```
/articles
/articles/show/(article id)
/articles/new
/articles/edit/(article id)
```

...etc.  I want to use the resources :articles route but this generates routes that are different.

```
/articles
/articles/(article id)/show
/articles/new
/articles/(article id)/edit/
```

In fact, this is what I get when I run rake routes

```
articles     GET    /articles(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
articles     POST   /articles(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
new_article  GET    /articles/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
article      GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
article      PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
article      DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
```

I am trying to avoid using this to get the behavior that I want.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Because it the app would still respond to the above routes.  Is there a simple way to change the routes to get the desired behavior?  And if so how?  If not then what should I do so that the app only responds to the desired URL structure?

Comment: Right now I just have `resources :articles` but I the generator for the controller added this type `get "articles/index"` which I had commented out.

Answer (score 3):

Just set up match routing for the specific controller methods you need to set it up for:

```
match 'articles/show/:id' => 'articles#show', :via => :get, :as => 'article'
#etc etc ...
```

And then include the resources for the ones you don't need to change

```
resources :articles, :only => [:index, :new]
```